# How do I return my records grouped by NULL and NOT NULL?

Tags: sql, null, group-by

I have a table that has a `processed_timestamp` column -- if a record has been processed then that field contains the datetime it was processed, otherwise it is null.

I want to write a query that returns two rows:

```
NULL        xx -- count of records with null timestamps
NOT NULL    yy -- count of records with non-null timestamps
```

Is that possible?

**Update:** The table is quite large, so efficiency is important. I could just run two queries to calculate each total separately, but I want to avoid hitting the table twice if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Oracle:

group by nvl2(field, 'NOT NULL', 'NULL')

Comment: Sweet -- that's a nifty custom function. (More here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/Char-Functions/NVL2xvalue1value2Returnsvalue1ifxisnotnullifxisnullvalue2isreturned.htm )

Comment: I don't know why, but it seems to work on my version of MariaDB (10.4.13) too

Answer (score 56):

In MySQL you could do something like

```
SELECT 
    IF(ISNULL(processed_timestamp), 'NULL', 'NOT NULL') as myfield, 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY myfield
```

Comment: This is awesome, i need to play around with the IF conditional some more

Comment: Best answer for MySQL.

Comment: Not working with group by statement in laravel :(

Answer (score 47):

In T-SQL (MS SQL Server), this works:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN Field IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE 'NOT NULL' END FieldContent,
  COUNT(*) FieldCount
FROM
  TheTable
GROUP BY
  CASE WHEN Field IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE 'NOT NULL' END
```

Comment: In Postgresql this worked for me as well,you can group by FieldContent as well in this case.

Answer (score 26):

Try the following, it's vendor-neutral:

```
select
    'null    ' as type,
    count(*)   as quant
    from       tbl
    where      tmstmp is null
union all
select
    'not null' as type,
    count(*)   as quant
    from       tbl
    where      tmstmp is not null
```

After having our local DB2 guru look at this, he concurs: none of the solutions presented to date (including this one) can avoid a full table scan (of the table if timestamp is not indexed, or of the indexotherwise). They all scan every record in the table exactly once.

All the CASE/IF/NVL2() solutions do a null-to-string conversion for each row, introducing unnecessary load on the DBMS. This solution does not have that problem.

Comment: This is a pretty large table -- hitting it twice like this is inefficient, no?

Comment: No, actually (at least in DB2 which is the DB I use), this solution will be as fast as all the decode/nvl2-type ones - they all have to perform a full table scan (my solution will process the same number of records overall but in two groups) - index on timestamp field reqd in both cases.

Comment: It'll be interesting to try this solution side-by-side with a vendor-specific one when I get to work tomorrow.

Comment: I came here to post this solution, but Pax Diablo beat me to it.  All the other solutions rely on converting the column to a string, which you are then counting.  In this case, chances are you never even have to touch any rows, because all the information you care about is in the index.

Comment: @Pax: I just came here by accident and noticed that this answer had a down-vote from me (I have no idea why I should have done this). Curiously, I was able to revert it to +1, even though it should have been much too old. Strange.

Comment: No probs, @Tomalak, I've noticed that before. You can't cancel a vote after a certain amount of time unless the Q/A is edited. But you can change your vote (why?, only the powers that be can answer that). Usually, if someone fixes a problem I downvoted for (but not enough to deserve an upvote), I just edit the Q/A a little so that I can cancel the vote.

Comment: @Pax: Then the down-vote must have been cast before revision #4. I still have no idea why I had cast it in the first place. At any rate - this was not at all meant to be a subtle way of asking for an up-vote from you. But thanks anyway. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Stewart,

Maybe consider this solution.  It is (also!) vendor non-specific.

```
SELECT count([processed_timestamp]) AS notnullrows, 
       count(*) - count([processed_timestamp]) AS nullrows 
FROM table
```

As for efficiency, this avoids 2x index seeks/table scans/whatever by including the results on one row.   If you absolutely require 2 rows in the result, two passes over the set may be unavoidable because of unioning aggregates.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 5):

If it's oracle then you can do:

```
select decode(field,NULL,'NULL','NOT NULL'), count(*)
from table
group by decode(field,NULL,'NULL','NOT NULL');
```

I'm sure that other DBs allow for similar trick.

Answer (score 3):

Another MySQL method is to use the [`CASE` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case), which can be generalised to more alternatives than `IF()`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN processed_timestamp IS NULL THEN 'NULL' 
            ELSE 'NOT NULL' END AS a,
       COUNT(*) AS n 
       FROM logs 
       GROUP BY a
```

Comment: IF() function works as well - if(processed_timestamp is null, 'null', 'not null')

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server (starting with 2012):

```
SELECT IIF(ISDATE(processed_timestamp) = 0, 'NULL', 'NON NULL'), COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ISDATE(processed_timestamp);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way in T-sql (sql-server)

```
select  count(case when t.timestamps is null 
                    then 1 
                    else null end) NULLROWS,
        count(case when t.timestamps is not null 
                    then 1 
                    else null end) NOTNULLROWS
from myTable t
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle

```
SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(TIME_STAMP_COLUMN)
FROM TABLE;
```

count(*) returns the count of all rows

count(column_name) returns the number of rows which are not NULL, so

```
SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(TIME_STAMP_COLUMN) NUL_COUNT,
                  COUNT(TIME_STAMP_COLUMN) NON_NUL_COUNT
FROM TABLE
```

ought to do the job.

If the column is indexed, you might end up with some sort of range scan and avoid actually reading the table.

Answer (score 1):

If your database has an efficient COUNT(*) function for a table, you could COUNT whichever is the smaller number, and subtract.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like Pax's solution, but if you absolutely require only one row returned (as I had recently), In MS SQL Server 2005/2008 you can "stack" the two queries using a CTE

```
with NullRows (countOf)
AS
(
    SELECT count(*) 
    FORM table 
    WHERE [processed_timestamp] IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT count(*) AS nulls, countOf
FROM table, NullRows
WHERE [processed_timestamp] IS NULL
GROUP BY countOf
```

Hope this helps

Comment: But then you're hitting the database twice -- inefficient. (Which must be why Pax deleted his solution.)

Comment: Pretty big approcach for such a simple problem, isn't it?

Comment: You're only hitting the database twice if your database doesn't optimise it.  Probably a safe assumption, but an assumption nonetheless.

Comment: Pax deleted his solution because it started getting downvotes, despite being the only non-vendor specific solution :-).  Probably better to have a comprehensive list of all the vendor-specific optimized solutions and readers can choose which one they want.

Comment: Actually, I'll put it back and take the hits - interesting to see how many downvotes it gets....

Comment: Well then this solution should get extra downvotes because it's inefficient AND vendor specific. There's another T-SQL solution that doesn't hit the database twice.

Comment: @Stewart Johnson.  CTE's *are* ANSI SQL:1999!  Also, All aggregate functions (of which count(*) is one) give a scalar result for the set they are given, in this case rows with, then rows without, values for that column.

Answer (score 0):

[T-SQL]:

```
select [case], count(*) tally
from (
  select 
  case when [processed_timestamp] is null then 'null'
  else 'not null'
  end [case]
  from myTable
) a
```

And you can add into the case statement whatever other values you'd like to form a partition, e.g. today, yesterday, between noon and 2pm, after 6pm on a Thursday.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Sum(Case When processed_timestamp IS NULL
                         Then 1
                         Else 0
                 End)                                                               not_processed_count,
          Sum(Case When processed_timestamp Is Not NULL
                         Then 1
                         Else 0
                 End)                                                               processed_count,
          Count(1)                                                                total
From table
```

Edit: didn't read carefully, this one returns a single row.