# How to count SQL data but also have a field that may be present or not?

Tags: sql, group-by, count, pivot

I'm trying to figure out the right SQL query to group data but also include a boolean (YES/NO) if *at least one* of the rows grouped has a certain value.

Here's a concrete example to help visualize:

Let's say I have some data like this, maybe in a table called "experiments" with fields like this:

```
id, experiment_name, user_id, created_at, completed_at
```

And let's say I have this data:

```
1, "test experiment", 23, 2019-09-10, NULL

2, "test experiment", 17, 2019-09-15, NULL

3, "test experiment", 23, 2019-09-18, 2019-09-19

4, "test experiment", 23, 2019-09-19, NULL
```

I want to write a SQL query that does a group_by the user_id so I can have a count, but also includes some boolean value of whether at least one of their rows included a completed_at value.

Thus, I can't just do:

```
SELECT user_id, count(*), completed_at from db group by user_id, completed_at;
```

That ends up like:

```
user_id  count(*)   completed_at

23            2       NULL

23            1       2019-09-19

17            1       NULL
```

What I'd like is some query that lets me end up with something like:

```
user_id     count(*)    did_complete?

23              3          TRUE

17              1          FALSE
```

But I'm stumped on that part. I tried searching SO here but I can't figure out how to even word this as a short, searchable question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use an aggregate function with a conditional expression to check if at least one record in the group has a non-null `completed_at` value:

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    COUNT(*) cnt, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN completed_at IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) did_complete
FROM experiments
GROUP BY user_id
```

I usually prefer using `0`/`1` rather than `TRUE/FALSE` since numbers are much more portable across different RDBMS than booleans.

Answer (score 1):

You should select nullable column as yes/no and than group by this field
Something like

```
SELECT user_id, count(*), switch if is null completed_at then 0 else 1 end as nullableField from db group by user_id, nullableField;
```

Also look at this question [How do I return my records grouped by NULL and NOT NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239545/how-do-i-return-my-records-grouped-by-null-and-not-null)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN completed_at IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HasCompleted,
count(*) AS CNT, 
MAX(completed_at) LastCompleted 
from db 
group by user_id;
```